# Compiling python-mcrypt in win32?

Tags: python, cross-compiling

Um, I'm stumped and really stuck (+_+) here after googling many sites. I'm using mingw32-gcc.exe from Dev-c++ compiler and currently following instructions from this [site](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/06/28/compiling-python-extensions-with-distutils-and-mingw).

Every time I try here's the result:

```
C:\Python26>python c:\python26\python-mcrypt-1.1\setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_ext
error: don't know how to compile C/C++ code on platform 'nt' with 'mingw32-gcc.exe' compiler
```

I've edited the distuils.cfg file in my c:\python26\lib\distuils\distuils.cfg with this parameter

```
[build]
compiler = mingw32-gcc.exe
```

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: Is it in your PATH? Also try using Cygwin.

Comment: Yes, downloading Cygwin is suck, if I do that mostly times, my Pc will be  infected with virus (ex. bot or worms..) from the internet. I've tried using Cygwin and mingw32 with installer directly from online repository..

Comment: Cygwin is 200% virus free. Also, how did you install the two? Did you install them from the GUI package manager?

Comment: Has this been resolved? I'm hitting a similar road block.

Answer (score 0):

You installed python outside of a compilation environment valids one include cygwin or mingw32 (wich is used by Dev-C++).

To use the command-line mode, you need to find the your compiler installation and find bat script which launch the shell with the proper parameters (This is needed for bith cygwin and mingw).

The alternative is to use [Microsft solution](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/C/4/3C4C7C9C-AAA0-4BD4-9C14-5BA29BDD7D4C/sua.pdf) for that problem.